# Why are some VS code debug variable properties darkened

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, debugging

While debugging in VS Code I noticed that some variables in objects are darkened. Are these properties at the prototype level?

Is there documentation on this?

[image: Image of VS Code debug panel showing an error object with darkened properties]